# Trying to get the Mail Poet list in a select

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to get mail poet list in a dropdown using the code below but i am only getting first value and id in option, although there are 5 lists available, what am i doing wrong?

```
    $mplistname = array(\MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0]['name']);
    $mplistid = array(\MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists()[0]['id']);
    $mplistoptions = array_combine($mplistid, $mplistname);

    foreach($mplistoptions as $key=>$value) {
            $mplistoptions[$key] = $value;
    }
```

Comment: You unecessary call api twice

Comment: i couldn't extract the name and id otherwise, what am i missing?

Comment: you can store output of `API::MP('v1')->getLists()` inside new variable and then access `name` and `id` from there

Comment: an example would be very helpful, thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Patryk said, don’t make two API calls when one suffices.

And you are getting only the first name and id, because you are *accessing* only the first entry in both your arrays … that’s what `[0]` does.

This should probably just be condensed to something like this:

```
$data = \MailPoet\API\API::MP('v1')->getLists();

foreach($data as $record) {
    // do stuff with $record['name'] and $record['id'] here
}
```